# How do you edit OrbitControls.js to your preferred keybindings?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried messing with the orbit controls library in three.js to change the camera controls.
[Orbit Controls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js)

I'd like the "middle mouse press down" (which is something that is not within the library, only scroll) to be the rotate function and not left-click.

```
// Mouse buttons
this.mouseButtons = { LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE, MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN };
```

Perhaps this code has something to do with it? I feel like turning it to this would be the easiest way without completely mutilating the library.

````
    this.mouseButtons = { LEFT: (EMPTY) , MIDDLE: **THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE**, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN };```
````

Comment: When we implemented the ability to customize `mouseButtons` we didn't fully implement all possibilities. This is my fault, sorry. Please refer to [PR #18348](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/18348). Once it's reviewed and merged, you'll be able to use the suggested code.

Comment: Download the source and change it. You don't have to wait for a PR

Comment: @ScieCode Thanks for the response, but what if I wanted to use middle mouse click and not wheel scroll for rotation?

Comment: `mouseButtons.MIDDLE` is responsible for controlling the middle mouse click. There's no way of modifying the scrolling action.

Comment: As @gman said, you don't need to wait for the PR. Feel free to use this version of [OrbitControls.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/71ee4ea9c32987db3fdd2575f1d9b304915ba94a/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) in the meanwhile.

Comment: @ScieCode Thank you so much